# asp:Image is not rendered at all inside asp:HyperLink

Tags: asp.net, image, hyperlink

I have this code in ASP.NET 4.5 / VS 2013

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="ht" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>'>
   <asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" CssClass="img-responsive" 
    ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Image") %>'></asp:Image>
</asp:HyperLink>
```

and the image inside hyperlink is not rendered at all, why?
I also have tried with static image link, but I get the same result.

I need the image inside hyperlink because I need a custom css class for the image

Comment: What is the resulting client-side markup?  What is the value of `Eval("Image")`?

Comment: <a id="MainContent_listImages_lnkViewImage_1" class="st btn btn-default" href="/pic-5/grunge-brushed-metal-texture">View Image</a>

Comment: I'm not certain an `asp:HyperLink` can contain markup like that.  Though the `asp:HyperLink` tag has an `ImageUrl` property, setting that should be roughly equivalent (though you'll need to do some tinkering to see how to set the `CssClass` of the resulting image, not the parent anchor).  You might also try a normal anchor tag instead of an `asp:HyperLink`, as anchor tags most definitely can contain other tags.

Comment: your code should work . can you cross check that your '<%# Eval("Image") %>'  has value. for this purpose take a label control assign to it.

Comment: if you have jpg type image then change your code .
<asp:HyperLink ID="ht" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>'>
   <asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" CssClass="img-responsive" 
    ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Image")+".jpg" %>'></asp:Image>
</asp:HyperLink>

Comment: If I move the exact ImageUrl to asp:hyperlink, the image is resolved in the hyperlink, but again, I need to display the image in a separate asp:Image in order to set it's css class

Comment: adding the .jpg extension does not make sense, since the <img> tag is not rendered at all inside the hyperlink control

Comment: Sounds like a publishing issue to me. Are you sure the code executing matches up with your source?

Comment: yes, and I have tried to local and on the remove server, same result.

Comment: ASP.NET has a tendency to act smart when you don't want it to. It might be choosing not the render the element because the ImageUrl is empty or null. I would take Amit's advice and try to see if you are getting anything back from Eval("Image"), as in: `<asp:HyperLink ID="ht" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>'><%# Eval("Image")%></asp:HyperLink>`

Comment: @danyim: yes check it .

Comment: ok, I have set the image manually, and the img tag still does not appear at all inside the hyperlink <a

Comment: I have botstrap 3 in this theme, is it possilbe to be affected by that? I think not. Because everything else in my site is working

Comment: I also have VS2013 and NET 4.5 which may not allow <asp:Image inside <asp:Hyperlink controls

Comment: @MarioM : I'm also using .net 4.5. and this code is working fine .
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx">
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/jquery.jpg" />
        </asp:HyperLink>
check your code are getting anything from '<%# Eval("Image") %>' or not

Comment: I am getting the right image url in the Eval, because if I move the Eval in the HyperLink Image Url then the image gets displayed.

Comment: @MarioM Which data control are you using with? GridView, Repeater or so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and it renders the image properly. The worst case, you can use [DataList.ItemDataBound Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.itemdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to bind the data.

### ASPX

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" 
     OnItemDataBound="DataList1_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="ht" runat="server">
            <asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" CssClass="img-responsive"/>
        </asp:HyperLink>    
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Code Behind

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataList1.DataSource = new List<MyClass>
        {
            new MyClass
            {
                Url = "http://www.google.com",
                Image = "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"
            },
            new MyClass
            {
                Url = "http://www.msn.com",
                Image = "http://col.stb00.s-msn.com/i/80/53CAC6A10B6248682CF221B24A92.gif"
            },
        };
        DataList1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
        e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var item = e.Item.DataItem as MyClass;

        var ht = e.Item.FindControl("ht") as HyperLink;
        ht.NavigateUrl = item.Url;

        var img = e.Item.FindControl("img") as Image;
        img.ImageUrl = item.Image;
    }
}
```

If you use DataSet or DataTable, you need to cast **DataItem** to **DataRowView**. `var dr = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;`. [look at this example.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19415539/296861)

Comment: Why don't you use eval?

Answer (score 0):

The `asp:HyperLink` Web Control renders into an anchor tag, with anything between the `<asp:HyperLink> ... </asp:HyperLink>` becoming the the value for the `Text` attribute.

I would suggest you try using an `asp:ImageButton` instead for your purpose.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnMyControl" CssClass="img-responsive" PostBackUrl="<%# Eval("Url") %>" ImageUrl="<%# Eval("Image") %>" />
```

[ImageButton API reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: who told you anything between hyperlink , will become text for that . 
i have working example. you can check too 
 <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx">
            <asp:Image ImageUrl="~/Desert.jpg" runat="server" />
        </asp:HyperLink>
this code showing image.

Comment: it's useless because I need to set the CSS property of the image to img-responsive

Comment: Do you need the image to be accessible server-side? Why not just use an `<img src='<%# Eval("Image") %>' />` inside the hyperlink?

Comment: I don't want to use imagebutton to have 50 postbacks on the photo gallery, I have tried img src='<%# Eval("Image") %>' /> but it does not work, img tag does not appear at all inside the hyperlink

Comment: @danyim I have tried that and nothing gets rendered inside the hyperlink tag